# Error is coming while using NetInfo in react native android application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building an android application using react native. Where I require to get network information. I followed the following steps...

1. Add  in AndroidManifest.xml.
2. Inject NetInfo in index.android.js
3. In ComponentDidMount is had written following code

   NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {

   ```
       alert(isConnected);

   });
   ```

But every time I am getting following error while running my code....

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'E:\Test Project\2017\ReactNative\R
  >   eactNativeApp\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.294 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

I do not know, what is exactly going on. I am following each steps mentioned in documentation. But still it is not working. Any one can give me few information ?